# Compile a jasper file from jrxml in a jrxml file? Is it possible?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a jrxml file and want to add a subreport expression. But I have only myFile.jrxml and cannot pass a jasper file. Is it possible to compile my jrxml file to a jasper file not with java code, but in the current jrxml file? And if possible, how to do this?

```
<subreportExpression  class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}+"/myFile.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
```

I tried:

```
<subreport  isUsingCache="true">

<connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
          <subreportExpression  class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport"><![CDATA[net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load($P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "myFile.jrxml"))]]></subreportExpression>

</subreport>
```

but an error occured:
SEVERE: Error evaluating expression : 
        Source text : net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load($P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "myFile.jrxml"))

Answer (score 3):

```
<subreportExpression>
  <![CDATA[JasperCompileManager.compileReport($P{SUBREPORT_DIR}+"/myFile.jrxml")]]>
</subreportExpression>
```

Comment: Thank you - this worked for me.  Appears to be the best answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

From what I've read in the Ultimate Guide the answer is no, it is not possible.  Why are you unable to compile the subreport to a jasper file?

Comment: Because I should pass some parameters from the parent jrxml.

Comment: You can pass parameters to a jasper file, you don't have to pass parameters to a jrxml then compile.  Just pass your parameters to the jasper and you should be okay.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, I am unaware of the codes used here, just open iReport 5.0. Open the `.jrxml` file it will show the conversion option readily on the screen. Give a path for saving `.jasper` file. Now you have `.jrxml` and it's editable `jasper`.